# Problem to dynamically change the Navbar due to the value of the localStorage variable

Tags: angular

I have been implementing a project in Angular 8. In this project there is a need to have the administration panel which includes different Navbar. To get into the administration panel you have to log in to it. Once you are logged into this, the `Navbar` should be dynamically changed to the one which is the admin nav bar - the change should be based on the boolean value from the login result. To do this, I tried to use the `BehaviorSubject`, but for some reasons all the time there is visible the false value. It looks as if the default value of `BehaviorSubject` which is false weren't updated

The Service:

```js
public isResults: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new   
BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

public _isResults$: Observable<boolean> =    
this.isResults.asObservable();
```

Login part in Service:

```js
yes:boolean = true;
no:boolean = false;

login(user:User){
 if (user.username != null && this.password != null) {
 localStorage.setItem('currentStatus',   
  JSON.stringify(this.yes));

  this.currentStatus =  
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentStatus'));

this.isResults.next(this.currentStatus); // updating the BehaviorSubject.
                   // BehaviorSubject should be updated with the boolean value taken from 
                   // the localStorage (in the localStorage the value is as it should be 
                   // but the BehaviorSubject isn't updated, when the value from
                   // localStorge is assigned to it)
```

AppComponent. In the AppComponent I try to subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject` to check the value:

```js
this.employeeService._isResults$.subscribe(
    value => {
       console.log(value);
    }
  )
```

the `value` is `false`;

Could I ask you for some help with the above?
Thanks,

Comment: Is your app component active when you are in login page?.. As I see you can go with the last value so ReplaySubject suits your case

Comment: Just remove that _isResults$ variable. Adding unneeded complexity. you can subscribe to your BehaviourSubject directly. So in your app.component, you can do isResults.subscribe(...) and from the login component isResults.next(value)

Comment: Thanks very much @Siddharth Pal@Mehdi for help